# function to validate million works fine. Need to ensure if it is the best way

Tags: javascript, angular

I have written a function to validate if a number is million and if million call the pipe that sets the number to two decimal places. The function works absolutely fine but need to ensure if it is the best way to do it

function call

```
let points = this.points;
    isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(points[0].point.high);

    txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + points[0].point.color + '">' + points[0].point.name + '</strong><br><br><table>';

    if (isMillionNumber)
        value = shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(points[0].point.high, 2);
    else
        value = shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(points[0].point.high, 0);
```

function to validate million

```
function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
    let  number = millionNumber.toString();
    var res = number.split(".");
    //check of the number contains decimals

    if (res.length > 1) {
        number = number.toString().split(".")[0];
        // check the length of the number
        if (number.length >= 7)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else {
        if (number.length >= 7)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just check to see if the number is greater than 1000000? Why do the comparison as a string?

Comment: The reason why i chose a string is because i need to check if the number contains a decimal and would anyways need to convert it to a string.

Comment: No, that is not true. You can check to see if `number === Math.floor(number)`. Also it's not clear why that matters if you're just checking to see if the number is bigger than 1000000.

Comment: And you don't even need the `Math.floor`. It doesn't matter whether the number has a fractional portion or not.

Comment: Whether it is "best" by which metric?

Comment: First and foremost: There's no reason whatsoever to make a round-trip through string for this. As Pointy pointed out, `return millionNumber >= 100000;` is all you need. In terms of the implementation, there's a fair bit of redundancy and chaff you can remove in that: 1. Once you've done the `split`, there's no need to do it again. Just set `number = res[0]` (or even `number = millionNumber.toString().split(".")[0];` which will work whether it has a `.` or not. Then any time you find yourself writing `if (a > b) return true; else return false;` stop and write `return a > b;` instead.

Comment: After reading through the above comments i feel pointy's answer is the best as it involves minimum amount of code and does the job    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                            return millionNumber >= 100000;
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to consider, are you using tslint? I highly recommend to use the Visual Studio Code and tslint combination. I mention this because probably you should put your conditional statements like this:

```
if (isMillionNumber) {
    value = shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(points[0].point.high, 2);
} else {
    value = shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(points[0].point.high, 0);
}
```

I know, I know, there is only one statement per condition, but is always a good practice to use curly braces.

Another thing I noticed. Are you verifying that **this.points** is not empty before you access it? If not, this may happen:

[image]

Based on the assumption that you are using Angular, why doing this?

```
txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + points[0].point.color + '">' + points[0].point.name + '</strong><br><br><table>';
```

One of the beauties of Angular is the separation of the html and the ts code. That line above could be something like this in your html file:

```
<strong [ngStyle]="{ 'color': textColor }">{{ someText }}</strong>
```

You could also call a method in the ngStyle, something like getColor() or whatever.

Being said all this, let's dissect your second block of code.

The first thing I noticed is that you are converting into a string a value that is already a string, and calling split again. You do not need to do this, you just have to do this:

```
if (res.length > 1) {
    **number = res[0];**
...
```

This is because you already converted to string and divided your number by using split.

In conclusion, I would reduce your code to this:

```
function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
    // assuming you number comes like this: 1000000.00
    let number = millionNumber.toString();

    if (number.includes(".")) {
        number = number.split(".")[0];
    }
    return (number.length >= 7);
}
```

As a last note, and this is my personal taste. I would **not** code an external function, would add it as a member function of my component. You may have your reasons to be doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks Armando. That was quite detailed and useful. Shall incorporate the changes. I would like to know what did you mean by I would not code an external function, would add it as a member function of my component. Could you give me an example

Comment: Sure. I mean, that instead of doing putting the function outside of the class component, I would add it as a member function. 

I believe you have something like this:
export class AppComponent {
       title = 'app';
    
       someOtherFunction() {
            someFunction();
       } 
    }

    function someFunction() {
      // empty
    }

But, I would put it like this:

    export class AppComponent {
        someOtherFunction() {
             this.someFunction();
        }

        someFunction() {
            // empty
        }
    }